# Certificate validation time delay when VPN is turned on

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, vpn, wif, timedelay

I've faced with problem with time delay during certificate validation. I'm using WIF and JWT Token Handler extension for my claim-based authentication. And in case VPN is turned on I have time delay(about 20 seconds) during certificate validation. Also I found the same behaviour with time delay when I opened Certificate Storage under Microsoft Management Console. Is there any way to avoid this issue?

Comment: Do not use VPN :) It is probably building certification path and downloads CRLs of CA in the path to verify that the JWT token has been signed with a valid certificate. Check, if these things are available through your VPN.

Comment: Thanks for replay, actually certificate issued by Verisign and CA is visible throw VPN, CLR also is visible. I'm not sure, but few months ago I so hardcoded time delay(sleep()) in System.IdentityModel dll. Maybe it occurs because of networkrouting

Answer (score 0):

I guess I found the reason here http://technet.microsoft.com/library/ee619754.aspx

It says:

> If a time-valid object is not found in the disk cache, the network
>   retrieval process starts. For each URL that is available for
>   retrieval, CryptoAPI starts a background thread to perform the network
>   retrieval of that designated object. By default, the calling thread
>   will wait up to 15 seconds for the retrieval to complete (as defined
>   in Group Policy).